# Swift 3.0: Paramater to check for action completion

Tags: ios, swift

I recently started learning app development and almost every tutorial I can find is not in swift 3, so sometimes I run into confusion when it comes to the syntax for certain things that have been changed.

```
//Take the user to the game screen from the intro scene
        let introLabel = childNode(withName: "introLabel")

            if introLabel != nil{
                let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1)

                introLabel?.run(action: fadeOut, completion: () -> Void)
        }
```

I have searched all around the internet and can't seem to find the missing thing I am supposed to put here (By completion: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
completion: () -> Void
```

It say that it will call a function `have no parameter ()` and return type is `Void`
The function is like this

```
func handleCompletion() -> Void {
    //Do something when complete
}
```

In your code, you can use like this.

```
introLabel?.run(action: fadeOut, completion: handleCompletion)
```

`handleCompletion` is my function above

Your can google for this by use `closure swift` or `first class function swift` keyword

Comment: Alright so I put the code that I wanted to execute after action completion in the handleCompletion function. I then used it in my code like you said and I get the error "argument labels (action: completion:) do not match any available overloads" so then I get rid of action: from the parameters and just use the variable so it looks like (fadeOut, completion: handleCompletion()) and then I get the error "Cannot convert value of type "void" (aka '()') to expected argument type '() -> Void'

Comment: @RichardParker When you pass in `handleCompletion()` as an argument to the `completion` parameter, you're not passing in the `handleCompletion` closure, you're passing in the result of evaluating handleCompletion`. That's what the `()` at the end does. It runs the closure and evaluates the return value. To pass in the closure itself, omit the `()`. Try instead: `(fadeOut, completion: handleCompletion)`

Comment: @RichardParker You can also define a closure inline, without have to make a named function like `handleCompletion`

Comment: Now I am pretty confused, any chance you can give me an example of this?  I think I get the concept of what your saying but I'm having a hard time finding the correct code to use.

Comment: google for 'closure swift' and 'first class function swift'